# What is the best way to increase a selected area over another area in a image using photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I am a beginner in Photoshop & trying to learn the following thing:
i want modify the below image

[image]

I want to increase following selected area over another area (yellow colored enclosed area) in a image using Photoshop:
[image]

in doing do i found following problems:

- I can't select the custom area, so i enclosed it by yellow color
- Can't correctly maintain the angle & other geometric balance

So whats best way to do this by maintaining correct angle & pixel perfect.
please suggest me Photoshop instructions. I want to learn it by myself.
Thank you very much

Comment: I don't understand your use of the word "increase" and I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish. Your talk about angles and geometric balance makes me think that you might want to look into Illustrator and vector graphics instead of Photoshop and pixel graphics, but it was just a thought.

Answer (score 1):

If you look your black shapes in high zoom, you see that they are anti-aliased, their borders are fuzzy to make them visually straight (=not appearing as stairs). Thus no selection can select those black shapes, all of them and nothing else. All possible selections will be compromises that leave out a little of the wanted or take along a little of the unwanted or both. Playing with selection antialias settings you maybe find an acceptable compromise.

Selections are harmful. You cannot draw them freely until you are ready. One unthinked click and it's gone. For example drawings are much more robust and there are also better tools to edit them.

My suggestion: Make a new layer, draw there a solid image which covers your wanted selection. That can be a vector shape or a bitmap pattern. Edit it until it's ready. High zoom, layer opacity+blending modes are essential tools to see the result and compare, if you use the bitmap version. Then make it to your selection. Try different antialias settings.

Professional image manipulators often draw paths. They can be edited until they are perfect and a selection is made. Mastering this should be also your goal.

I would make a copy of the image layer and adjust its contrast and colors as clear as possible. Then I would draw with the pen tool (clicking only) a path, edit it perfect with the direct selection tool and finally make a selection, this:

[image]

High zoom makes imperfections visible and the corner points are easy to move without destroying the straightness and other points. Moving the selected point is possible with arrow keys even outside the visible area.

Hopefully this was coarse and precise enough.

ADD: If this happens to be the whole image, not a small part of it, redrawing as vector shapes, even going to Illustrator for it, should be considered.

Answer (score 1):

The following method should work with any version of Photoshop from about CS4 and later.

Draw the shape with the Pen Tool, set to "shape" in the tool options along the top.

It might help if you temporarily reduce the opacity of the shape layer so you can see through it. Then you can adjust the position of the anchors with the Direct Selection Tool.

[image]

Duplicate the layer, and then *Edit > Transform Path > Flip Horizontal*. Click and drag the shape over to the other side.

[image]